# Python 3 Matplotlib installation failure on FreeBSD resulting in "legacy-install-failure"

Tags: python, matplotlib, freebsd

We are working with a python 3.7 installation on FreeBSD and are trying to install MatPlotLib.
When running `python3 -m pip install matplotlib` we received the below messages along with the output and the process failed.

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> matplotlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Further up the response, the following block appeared:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
  Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
  Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for matplotlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [613 lines of output]
```

We are aware the the response to this kind of thing has been to make sure that pip, setuptools and wheel are fully updated and we have checked and they are.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could be nice if you specify which version of `FreeBSD` you are using, 'cause the current `13.1` uses `Python39` ; you could install `matplotlib` through the port collections (`math/py-matplotlib`), or with its package (`pkg install py-matplotlib`).

Comment: The server in question is FreeBSD 12.2 
We have access to Python39 but that is it's own issue that we were trying to avoid since we have a stable 38 build mostly at this point

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from here:

> `ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib`

A wheel is an archived Python project consisting of one or more packages and their dependencies.

So, `pip` cannot proceed because it probably encountered some versioning conflicts.

( `python3 -m pip list |less` could help to find the bad guy)

From the FreeBSD-12.2-RELEASE ports collection, `py-matplotlib` **BUILD** depends on:

- Python-3.7.9

  - matplotlib-3.3.1
  - numpy-1.16.6
  - pillow: >6.2
  - pyparsing >=0
  - certifi: >=0.10

Try install `matplotlib` through the port tree (`math/py-matplotlib`) instead, which guaranty compatibility if the dependencies have been installed through the port tree. If not, you could reinstall all dep. according to the `matplotlib` needs. The `pip list` above will show you what's going on.

You could either install it through `pkg install`, but it requires some precaution on a server: you have to check `etc/pkg/pkg.conf` (both system and local) and see if update is set to `latest`, `quaterly` of `release` ; in your case, `release` seems the right choice, according to how the system was previously configured.

For python packages that require compilation steps, like `matplotlib`, I used to install them through the ports collection (or the pkg repo), unless I really know them and know what they need. You will save your time.

Comment: So we have the build dependencies you list, and  `pkg install math/py-matplotlib` runs but does not seem to do this particular version of matplot lib
we have, when using python3 -m pip list
`certifi                           2021.5.30`
`numpy                             1.21.6`
`Pillow                            9.2.0`
`pyparsing                         3.0.9`

Comment: If you install `mpl [matplotlib]` through the port collection (that comes with your FreeBSD-12.2RELEASE), it will install its dependencies as well (build and run deps), according to the port version of `mpl` from the port collection (see the `PORTVERSION` and `PORTREVISION` in the `Makefile` in `math/py-matplotlib`); when you install through `pip`, it doesn't always match other python package version ('cause deps. could comes from either port, or pip, or manually). you have to ensure a unique source of installation (or know exactly what you need), in order to match compatibilities.  See ?

Comment: Some edit have been done in the answer.

Comment: Hi, we ran into an issue trying to use the ports collection, we got the following error which seems very non-specific

`Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/math/py-matplotlib
*** Error code 1`

Comment: could come from many issues (network access for DC, user permissions, ...), your output messages seem not complete, anyway, that's another question.